# How Thread uses software to protect datastructure

Tags: process, linuxthreads

Hii ALL,
         I started reading about Threads and came to know about Thread uses software and Process uses hardware to protect datastructure...But could anyone elaborate this fact more??

Answer (score 1):

In Linux both threads & process are same, only difference between them sharing of Virtual memory. Threads run in address space of process. Threads also have a associated task_struct.